# WordPress BlogInfo('Name')

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

For WordPress, whenever I run the script below, the function `bloginfo('name')` echoes, but it doesn't `echo` inside the `<h1> </h1>` tags. Is the way of echoing `bloginfo` incorrect, or does `bloginfo` always break?:

```
<?php
if (con) {
    echo "<h1>" . bloginfo('name') . "</h1>";
}
?>
```

The script below works, but it spawns empty `<h1> </h1>` tags when the condition is false, which isn't necessary.

```
<h1>
<?php
if (con) {
    echo bloginfo('name');
}
?>
</h1>
```

Comment: Please use `echo "<h1>", bloginfo('name'), "</h1>";` to prevent pointless concatenation before output.

Comment: You do not need echo to show the content of bloginfo('name'). You can read more about bloginfo() here http://wplurn.com/wordpress-bloginfo-explained/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `echo` to retrieve the bloginfo.

[**`bloginfo()` documentation**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)

> This always prints a result to the browser. If you need the values for use in PHP, use get_bloginfo().

Instead of using echo, you can do something like this:

```
<h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
```

Or, if you want to store the blog name in a variable, you can use [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) as suggested in the documentation:

```
<?php 
$blog_title = get_bloginfo();
?>
<h1> <?php echo $blog_title; ?> </h1>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 `blog_info` outputs the value directly while `get_bloginfo` returns the value.

Answer (score 1):

`bloginfo()` prints the information without needing to echo it. `bloginfo()` actually seems to return nothing at all, hence why your `echo bloginfo('name');` is not working as expected. You can find more information about how `bloginfo()` works here; [Wordpress Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)
.

From the [examples section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo#Examples), you can find the following example usage;

```
<h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
```

If you want to retrieve blog information as a string, you can use `get_bloginfo()` with the same options that `bloginfo()` supports. More information about `get_bloginfo()` can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to `echo` use [get_bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo):

```
echo "<h1>" . get_bloginfo('name') . "</h1>";
```

Additionally, `name` is the `default parameter`, so you even really need it:

```
echo "<h1>" . get_bloginfo() . "</h1>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here : [Function_Reference/bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)
The bloginfo function does nothing else then echo-ing get_bloginfo() as you can [see here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/general-template.php#L367).
So if you want you can use get_bloginfo that you can echo... but your code will also work if you change it just a little bit:

```
<?php if (con) {
    echo "<h1>"; 
    bloginfo('name'); 
    echo "</h1>";
} ?>
```

Probably using get_bloginfo() is more visible but I wanted to show you how you can use your initial code.